# Onclick attribute for <p> tags

Tags: javascript

I'm simply testing out JavaScript, trying to get a feel for it, and I happened to run into a little trouble along the way. The oncllick attribute isn't doing what I intend for it to do with the "p" tag. I want the paragraph to turn blue when I click it, but the style is changed to blue during loading. Help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="test">This is a test. This is a test.</p>
<script>
var x;
x=document.getElementById("test")

function changeColor()
 {
    x.style.color="blue";
 }
    x.onclick=changeColor()
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the parentheses:

```
x.onclick=changeColor;
```

The way you have it there, you are calling the function immediately and assigning the result (`undefined`) to the `onclick` event handler. You need to assign the function itself to the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Set the onclick handler to the function *name*:

```
x.onclick = changeColor
```

Or call your `changeColor` fn inside an anonymous function that you assign to onclick:

```
x.onclick = function(){changeColor();}
```

...with the later method you also call other fns if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

change color does not have brackets inside it. Try editing it to this...

```
x.onclick = changeColor;
```

changecolor() is not correct as it is not a reserved method. For example Date().